# React state updates when using object, but not when using array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about some weird behavior when using React state.

If I change the default type of the `groupedFormErrors` variable in the helper function to `[]` instead of `{}` the state in the page element `formErrors` doesn't update. Would be great if somebody could explain why this happens.

Page element

```js
const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState();

const signUpHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await submitForm();
    if (response.status === 422) {
        setFormErrors(groupFormErrors(response));
    }
};
```

Helper function

```js
export default function GroupFormErrors(response) {
    let groupedFormErrors = {}; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This here
    if (response.status === 422) {
        response.data.forEach((error) => {
            if (groupedFormErrors.hasOwnProperty(error.param)) {
                groupedFormErrors[error.param].push(error.msg);
            } else {
                groupedFormErrors[error.param] = [];
                groupedFormErrors[error.param].push(error.msg);
            }
        });
    }
    return groupedFormErrors;
}
```

Comment: `GroupFormErrors` or `groupFormErrors` , are you calling the right function?

Comment: `groupedFormErrors` shouldn't be an array based on what you are showing. You can turn it into an array before returning it from the function via `Object.values(groupedFromErrors)`, which would get rid of the keying by param and only return the values.

Comment: @AlanOmar Yes I'm sure the right function is called. As I said the code works when using `{}` but not when using `[]`.

Comment: Also I was playing around with it and even though the state seems to not be updating it actually is.